# jQuery uses utf-8 on local server (post\get) and CP1251 on remote

Tags: jquery, codeigniter, post, get, cart

On local server jQuery .post/.get looks like "Content-Type: text/html" but on remote server use CP1251. And my Cyrillic text is encoded.

Why it happens on remote server ?

All files are in utf-8 without BOM, DB is in UTF-8, I send header as header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');

```
      $(document).ready(function() { 

      $("td.submit_product form").submit(function() {

           var id = $(this).find('input[name=product_id]').val();
           var qty = $(this).find('input[name=quantity]').val();
           var cat_id = $(this).find('input[name=category_id]').val();

       $.post(baseurl + "product/add_cart_item", { product_id: id, quantity: qty,   category_id:   cat_id, ajax: '1' },
function(data){
if(data == 'true'){
        $.get(baseurl + "product/show_cart", function(cart){
    $("#cart_content").html(cart);

    });

        $.get(baseurl + "product/cart_total", function(cart){
    $("#cart_total").html(cart);

    });


        }else{
            alert("Продукт не существу́ет");
        }   

     }); 

    return false;
    });

});
```

Is only one way to decode .get data ?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I read that people faced issues when they would like to use CP1251 but content type is UTF-8. jQuery as I understand use utf-8 by default, so I'm confused...

Comment: On hosting I enabled mbstring.internal_encoding:UTF-8, it was set in default.